# What makes an "object" for De Broglie matter waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

De Broglie theory of matter waves stipulates that the frequency increases with the weight of the object.

However I believe there is no physical definition of an "object", it's an arbitrary category.

We generally consider that an object is the sum of its parts: Let's take [nunchucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment#Galileo's_experiment) for example, how do you move from the frequency of each stick to the frequency of the whole nunchucks?

[image]

Comment: perhaps this is related : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322753047_A_Short_Note_on_the_de_Broglie_Wavelengths_of_Composite_Objects

Answer (score 0):

The simple present answer  is : there are no matter waves in the present theory of quantum mechanics. Matter does not wave in space and time .The probability of finding the *matter particles* has wave properties. See [this experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) with one electron at a time to understand what the frequency of a particle wave looks like.

The de Broglie equation was on the path of modeling data that led to the discovery of the [theory of Quantum mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) It holds good in the probabilistic realm of quantum mechanical solutions and is irrelevant for large dimensions.

The theory now depends on extra axiomatic assumption on solutions of mathematical differential equations, so as to fit observations and data. The de [Broglie relation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/debrog.html#c1),as also the Bohr planetary model of the atom, belong to the time before the quantum mechanical theory was validated, and led to its construction.

So the "objects" in order to fullfil the de Broglie relation  have to be quantum mechanical entities, mainly in dimensions smaller than those defined by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

Macroscopic objects, from the size of micrometer on, are classical objects and can be modeled  with classical mechanics and thermodynamics to great accuracies.

So for the object in your picture, there would be little difference between the De Broglie wavelength frequency as it will be a very very high frequency , and making it twice that makes no difference in its detectability. The probabilities fall at the classical points.

Comment: what about sub micrometer nunchucks then ?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi at nanometer particle dimensions quantum mechanics dominates, i.e. the wave nature is in the probability distributions .